# Android application crash at unknown source

Tags: java, android, logcat

I have an application which crashed 2 times randomly with a weird logcat message.

Here is it (both crashes are identical):

```
05-17 15:45:56.792 31082-31082/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                               Process: net.mycustom.application, PID: 31082
                                               java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'net.mycustom.application.tools.i net.mycustom.application.MyService.a(java.lang.Integer)' on a null object reference
                                                   at net.mycustom.application.tools.a.b.onCreateDialog(Unknown Source:83)
                                                   at android.app.DialogFragment.onGetLayoutInflater(DialogFragment.java:411)
                                                   at android.app.Fragment.performGetLayoutInflater(Fragment.java:1339)
                                                   at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1298)
                                                   at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addAddedFragments(FragmentManager.java:2426)
                                                   at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2205)
                                                   at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2161)
                                                   at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2062)
                                                   at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:738)
                                                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:280)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6706)
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

I have files in **net/mycustom/application/tools** (but there is nothing like "i").

Also I have a service here: **net/mycustom/application/MyService.java** (there is nothing like "a" in this service.)

How can I hunt down this issue? (Unknown source?)

Comment: This Q shall have been asked before but my intention was to decode the obfuscated names in my classes. Null pointer exception is clear I just had no idea where should I search it for. Therefore it might be better to point to proguard duplicates and not the nullpointer one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is likely ProGuard changed a method's name to `a`. Try deobfuscating the trace (as given in many tutorials that you can search up), and see the method's actual name. Then try to figure what is causing the `NullPointerException`.

*(the OP asked for how they can hunt the issue down, not what exactly is the solution)*